# TimeTable function not working

Tags: java, class, user-interface, netbeans, methods

I'm trying to write a code that'll generate a timetable. The function compiles fine but the results aren't what I'm expecting.

The method:

```
         public String generateTimeTable(){
    //2 arrays for all the months of the year and days of the week.
    String[] months = {"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"};
    String[] days = {"Mon","Tue","Wed","Thur","Fri","Sat","Sun"};



    DateTime today = new DateTime();
    DateTime start = today.plusDays(1).withTime(8, 0, 0, 0); // this makes it start at 8am the next day
    String finalString = "On" + " " + days[start.getDayOfWeek()-1] + " "+ start.getDayOfMonth() + " " + months[start.getMonthOfYear() - 1] + "\n"; //This is the string for the first day.
    // It should return something like "On Mon 13 February
    ArrayList<Course> list = listOfCourses(); //get a sorted list of courses



    while (start.toLocalDate().isBefore(this.startOfExams)) { // loop for everyday up until the start of exams
        String sub1 = list.get(0).toString() + "...from " + new Interval(start, start.plusHours(3)).toString().substring(11, 16) + " to " + new Interval(start, start.plusHours(3)).toString().substring(41, 46) + "\n";
        finalString += sub1;
        finalString += "\n";




        String break1 = "break...from " + new Interval(start.plusHours(3), start.plusHours(4)).toString().substring(11, 16) + " to " + new Interval(start.plusHours(3), start.plusHours(4)).toString().substring(41, 46) + "\n";
        // String break1 = "break..." + new Interval(start.plusHours(3), start.plusHours(4)) + "\n";
        finalString += break1;
        finalString += "\n";


        String sub2 = list.get(1).toString() + "..." + new Interval(start.plusHours(4), start.plusHours(7)) + "\n";
        finalString += sub2;
        finalString += "\n";


        String break2 = "LunchBreak...You need to eat! " + new Interval(start.plusHours(7), start.plusHours(8)) + "\n";
        finalString += break2;
        finalString += "\n";



        String sub3 = list.get(2).toString() + "..." + new Interval(start.plusHours(8), start.plusHours(10)) + "\n";
        finalString += sub3;
        finalString += "\n";


        String break3 = "break..." + new Interval(start.plusHours(10), start.plusHours(11)) + "\n";
        finalString += break3;
        finalString += "\n";


        String sub4 = list.get(3).toString() + "..." + new Interval(start.plusHours(11), start.plusHours(13)) + "\n";
        finalString += sub4;
        finalString += "\n";


        String break4 = "break..." + new Interval(start.plusHours(13), start.plusHours(14)) + "\n";
        finalString += break4;
        finalString += "\n";


        String sub5 = list.get(4).toString() + "..." + new Interval(start.plusHours(14), start.plusHours(15)) + "\n";
        finalString += sub5;
        finalString += "\n";


        String sub6 = list.get(5).toString() + "..." + new Interval(start.plusHours(15), start.plusHours((int) 15.5)) + "\n";
        //finalString += sub6;
        //finalString += "\n";


        start = start.plusDays(1); // Move along to the next day.

        finalString += "\n";
        finalString += "On" + " " + days[start.getDayOfWeek()-1] + " "+ start.getDayOfMonth() + " " + months[start.getMonthOfYear() - 1] + "\n";


    }
    return finalString + "EXAMM DAYYY!";


}
```

However after taking this data, I tried to test it with sample info:

```
                  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LocalDate examStart = new LocalDate(2016, 3, 1);

    Course chem = new Course("Chemistry", 2, examStart);
    Course math = new Course("Mathematics", 5, examStart);
    Course phys = new Course("physics", 8, examStart);
    Course french = new Course("French", 5, examStart);
    Course Bio = new Course("Biology", 3, examStart);
    Course eng = new Course("English", 6, examStart);


    TimeTable tt = new TimeTable(2016, 3, 1);

    tt.addCourse(chem);
    tt.addCourse(math);
    tt.addCourse(phys);
    tt.addCourse(french);
    tt.addCourse(Bio);
    tt.addCourse(eng);

    //FIRST THINGS FIRST: complete testing of updating confidence.
    //tt.updateConfidence("French", 1);

    String finals = tt.generateTimeTable();

    System.out.print(finals);




}
```

But instead of printing out my timetable, it only prints out On Fri 1 Apr
EXAMM DAYYY!

Anyone get why that may be so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Months are indexed from 0, not 1, in the Java `Date` class. So you're creating a timetable for 1 April, not 1 March. It's possible that this is what you intended; I'm not sure.

In any case, you're constructing a timetable for 1 April, and then setting the start date as 1 April plus one day, i.e., 2 April. This is causing problems with your `while` loop, which never runs: the start date is after the exam date.

Something else that you'll need to fix is that you're not looping through the `list` that you generate. You're using fixed indexes to retrieve the elements, which might work with your current setup, but it's very fragile: if you change the number of courses, you'll have to remember to change the `while` loop body. Best to use a `for` loop to go through the list and print the elements. This is a problem you're not really hitting at the moment, though, because your `while` loop isn't being executed at all.

It would help you to learn to use the debugging facilities in your IDE: you can step through the code line by line, and see what gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are running the program on 31st March, so 
your dates variable used in program are evaludated as below
 examStart = 1st March 2016 and 
start = 31st March (today)+1 day i.e. 1st april.

while loop condition is evaludated to false i.e. start is not before examstart
hence only those strings are printed which are evaluated outside loop.